# ESRI JS API - Buffer FaetureLayer

Tags: arcgis-maps-sdk-javascript, geometry, buffer

I have a Feature Layer that I would like to buffer using user input and a geometry service.

FeatureLayer:

```
    var texasPipeline = new FeatureLayer(pipeURL, {
        mode: FeatureLayer.MODE_ONDEMAND,
        outFields: ["*"],
        definitionExpression:texasPipeQuery
    });
```

BufferParameters:

```
        var params = new BufferParameters();
        params.distances = [distance];
        params.unit = units;
        params.outSpatialReference = map.spatialReference;
        params.geometries = texasPipeline;
        map.graphics.clear();
        geomSvc.buffer(params, showBuffer);
```

The server is returning an error saying that geometries must be supplied. My guess here is that i need to pass in the geometry of the FeatureLayer as opposed to the FeatureLayer itself. How do i get at the geometries of the FeatureLayer and appropriately pass that into the BufferParameters??

EDIT:
Additionally I have tried to loop through as you can see in the code bellow. passing the array of geometries into the BufferParameters still does not return successfully.

```
        var texasPipelineGeom = [];
        var graphics = texasPipeline.graphics;
        for (var G in graphics) {
            var g = graphics[G]["geometry"];
            console.log(g);
            texasPipelineGeom.push(g);
        }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think your `for` loop is incorrect. Since `texasPipeline.graphics` is an array, you would use `forEach` instead of `for ... in`. You can get even fancier by using `array.map` to turn them into an array of graphics in one line. Here's a JSFiddle illustrating that. Hope this helps!

https://jsfiddle.net/gavinr/rbcagx93/